# How to find a field/column source in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access

I've columns/fields in a table in MS Access which are being copied and exported from other tables. Is there anyway to find what those tables are and their fields/column sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are are no direct ways for this. You can use tools like [Access Dependency Checker](http://www.accessdependencychecker.com/) for searching all occurrences of destination column names and then analyse VBA code and queries. Even this method doesn't guarantee correct results because names can be generated by VBA/macro code and stored in database tables.